# Navigating to another page JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I wrote a jsf application, this app inserts the data into mysql database and shows some of the inserted details in another page.

I am successful in inserting the values into database, but unable to redirect to the other page even after writing the navigation rule.

My action code

```
<div align="center"><p:commandButton label="Submit"  action="#{userData.add}"   align="center" ajax="false" /></div>
```

Navigation rule

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>UserData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>userData.UserData</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>home.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/home.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <to-view-id>/badge.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

If i write the face-redirect true then its showning an error, or if i write the action to the other page then its not inserting the values to database.

Comment: No in the action property of command button like this action="#userData.add?faces-redirect=true"

Comment: I wrote <redirect/> but still the page is not navigating now my faces-config.xml looks like this                                                                                      <navigation-case>
   <to-view-id>/badge.xhtml</to-view-id>
   <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>

Comment: I executed the insert sql statement in add method , can you tell me how to write <from-outcome>

Comment: Now i added action listener for command button and wrote a method in class like this  public String edit(){
 return "badge";
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop reading JSF 1.x resources and get rid of all that JSF 1.x-style `<managed-bean>` and `<navigation-rule>` entries in `faces-config.xml`.

The proper JSF 2.x approach for your `action="#{userData.add}"` is as below:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserData {

    public String add() {
        // ...

        return "/badge.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

}
```

No additional XML mess needed. Also no action listeners.

Links to JSF 2.x tutorials/books can be found in [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)
- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)